# OAuth2 client fails when redirecting from the authorization step

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

In my current spring-boot, I am trying sign in the user using an external OAuth2 server. The problem right now is that when I execute the application, after the authorization being successful, the user should be redirected back to the application. When this happens, I got an error.

My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.provider=mercadolivre
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-id=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-secret=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.authorization-uri=https://auth.mercadolivre.com.br/authorization
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.token-uri=https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token
```

My security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

The error I am facing right now:

[image]

What is the problem here?

**update**

I try add this line to my `applicatio.properties` file:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
```

and now I am getting this error:

[image]

with the browser developer console open:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `redirect-uri` to something else... It's better if you use a template string like the one the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-register-clientregistrationrepository-bean) uses:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
```

That's the uri that will process the authorization code the authorization server sends back. If you want the user to be redirected to some page after successful authentication, do something like this in `configure()`:

```java
http.
    ...
    .oauth2Login()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/");
```

Comment: I need map this `redirect-uri` in my controller, and do some processing with the data received?

Comment: Nope! Spring Security does that for you automatically in OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter

Comment: Ok, I've tried that, but now I am getting this error: `[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 406 Not Acceptable: [Media is not supported]`.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct token uri? The endpoint you provided isn't sending back a response with an "application/json" media type

Comment: I use exactly the url's shown here: https://developers.mercadolivre.com.br/en_us/authentication-and-authorization#Server-side

Comment: I think the problem is that Spring makes the POST for the authenntication code with FORM parameters, whereas mercadolibre expects no body, only query parameters

Comment: Is it possible change this Spring behavior?

Comment: It'd hidden deep in the Spring Security oauth classes... The class you're interested in is OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter, which is in OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter , which is in DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient, which is in OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider, which is in OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider. I suggest you ask that as a new question.